# iptables forwarding all excluding local server

Tags: iptables

These are the rules I am using:

```
iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlan5 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface wlan3 -j ACCEPT
```

I have wlan5 with 192.168.1.100, and wlan3 with 10.0.0.1.
I make my laptop a wifi repeater with 2 wifi cards.

So people connect to wlan3, the gateway is 10.0.0.1, and everything redirects to wlan5 [gw 192.168.1.1].

Now, this is working great, **except** I cannot access a local HTTP server hosted on my laptop.  It is hosted on my laptop, and it works as localhost, or 10.0.0.1:

```
$ curl -I 10.0.0.1
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 02:35:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://10.0.0.1/index.php
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Ok, so here is where the problem comes up.  A client on my sharing network [wlan3] with IP 10.0.0.20 tries to access 10.0.0.1:80 and it cannot connect:

```
$ wget http://10.0.0.1                                       
Connecting to 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

It can ping 10.0.0.1 and even ping external IP.  so it has internet connection, which is the point, but it cannot access the HTTP, I believe because of the iptables rules.
right after the error, I get this on my laptop syslog:

```
Feb 25 21:36:19 toshi kernel: [57806.285170] Inbound IN=wlan3 OUT= MAC=9c:b7:0d:a5:45:67:a8:26:d9:3e:04:21:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.20 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=28282 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58343 DPT=80 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

So the question is, how can I exclude forwarding IP requests to 10.0.0.1 not forward to wlan5?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there's no active firewall (ufw, etc...)? The syslog line you posted is an iptables log that is only pushed to syslog if there's a `-j LOG` target. Your `iptables` commands flush all rules and delete all custom chains, so nothing should be logged. Can you post the output of `sudo iptables-save`.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5569496/   Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I found out that it was working after I did that paste.  But later it stopped again so here is a [bigger output] paste: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5569685/

Comment: You do have a firewall program that automatically configures iptables. Don't you remember to enable any firewall? The most common, and disabled by default, is ufw. Run `sudo ufw status` to check if it is enabled, and `sudo ufw disable` to disable it.

Comment: It says "Status: inactive"..

Answer (score 1):

edit: once again, after I thought the problem was fixed, it just stopped working again without me issuing NO more iptables commands.  I cannot figure out why it keeps working, and then not working. >.<

---

I found a different iptables command that works to share my internet from 1 [long range] wifi device to another [internal]:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan5 -j MASQUERADE
```

instead of the iptables commands in the question.  And this makes it so I can still access internet, and still access http/ssh on 10.0.0.1 from 10.0.0.20.

Comment: This is happening because some (firewall?) program is automatically setting iptables rules. You only have to discover which program is "messing" with iptables. Run `dpkg -l | grep -i firewall`, maybe it'll show something related to firewall programs.

Comment: All that shows up is ufw [which is disabled] and firestarter.  But firestarter is not running.  Also I use `wicd` to connect to wifi.  It seems to me: when I'm not connected, run the iptables rules run hostapd, the connection works [with wlan3].  But when I connect to internet on wlan5, then iptabes-save is a few times longer with lots of rules with IP addresses that were not there before.

Answer (score 0):

The `iptables-save` [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5569685/) you posted shows the following custom chains in the filter table: INBOUND, OUTBOUND, LOG_FILTER, LSI and LSO. Firestarter creates 5 chains, all named exactly like that.

I'm sure your problem is caused by Firestarter. Open it and check if it's really disabled.

References:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1751064.html
- http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2010/10/msg01435.html